# Understand C code implementing CRC for Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, crc

Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) uses 24-bit CRC with generator polynomial of

> x^24 + x^10 + x^9 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1

I came across [this article](https://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=05.Projects&proj=11.%20Bluetooth%20LE%20fakery) which implemented this CRC in C, using "the initial value of 0x555555". I paste the code as follows:

```
void btLeCrc(const uint8_t* data, uint8_t len, uint8_t* dst){
    uint8_t v, t, d;
    while(len--){
        d = *data++;
        for(v = 0; v < 8; v++, d >>= 1){    
            t = dst[0] >> 7;
            dst[0] <<= 1;
            if(dst[1] & 0x80) dst[0] |= 1;
            dst[1] <<= 1;
            if(dst[2] & 0x80) dst[1] |= 1;
            dst[2] <<= 1;

            if(t != (d & 1)){
                dst[2] ^= 0x5B;
                dst[1] ^= 0x06;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

However, I have a hard time understanding this code. It seems a little different from the CRC code I saw in the past. For example, he used initial value of 0x555555 rather than 0x000000 or 0xffffff, and the bit manipulation looked magic to me. Can anyone explain what he was doing? Thanks!

Comment: i think this code may be mathematically proved then tuned. i don't know exactly, but in energy consumption's point of view, turning multiplications to bitwise operations should definitely cost less power.

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble?  It looks like the inner loop is just processing things 1 bit-position at a time, maintaining the 24-bit shift-register in `dst`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr This code is used in an 8-bit microcontroller. I guess doing CRC with bit manipulation is better.

Comment: @shva i had been working on embedded system when i was in university and read some about CRC. i have almost forgotten everything, but i still have the impression that CRC can be mapped into a whatever space and turned into bitwise operations. i think M sequence are with the same idea. correct me if you find something.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I have trouble with the for loop. dst[0] seems to correspond to the highest byte of CRC polynomial (0x00065B) while dst[2] to the lowest byte. Although the for loop processes bit-by-bit of a data byte, I don't understand what it does before the if statement, and why the condition of if statement is (t != (d & 1)).

Comment: The `t != (d & 1)` is the equivalent of exclusive-or'ing those two bits, and then taking the action if the exclusive-or is `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `uint8_t` is the only available integer type, which would explain why the author is shifting and exclusive-oring a 24-bit value, `dst[0..2]` 8 bits at a time.

The code implements a basic CRC shift register, where the data is shifted in a bit at a time, and the CRC exclusive-or'ed with the polynomial when the data bit exclusive-or'ed with the bit shifted out of the register is one.  Note that the exclusive-or of the polynomial is only on two of the three register bytes due to the fact that the polynomial's highest power below x<sup>24</sup> is x<sup>10</sup>.

The initialization with `0x555555` instead of `0xffffff` is simply a matter of taste.  Initializing with any value other than zero is a good idea, since then an initial string of zeros in the data doesn't leave the CRC unchanged.

Comment: I realized he probably was implementing CRC with shift registers like in [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/NUdQH0F.png). Please correct me if I am wrong. But still, I don't understand why he initialized the registers with 0x555555 not 0x000000 in this case. I think the initialization value affects the final computed checksum.

Comment: Yes, the diagram is what's going on.  I said why it is being initialized with `0x555555`.  Of course it affects the result.  That's the whole point.  So long as the same process is used at both ends, it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

In Bluetooth Low Energy, the CRC shift register is initialized to 0x555555 for advertising and to a random value (shared during the connection process) for connected devices.